# Why are there three different numbers for the amount of revisions I've made? And which one is real?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, edits, badges

The other day, I noticed I was getting close to the Copy Editor badge, based on the number of revisions I've made in my user profile. However, when the 500 mark arrived, and went, I still had no badge, so I went digging.

At first I thought, oh that says "*Revisions*", and the badge says "Edited 500 *Posts*". Maybe I've edited individual posts multiple times. After some more digging, however, I noticed some odd discrepancies.

There are (to my knowledge, at least) three different ways a user can see their revision progress.

1. User Profile -> Activity -> Revisions
2. Review Queue -> Badge Progress Overlay
3. Users page -> Editors -> Filter by "All" -> Type in Username

**The problem is that each one of these gives a completely different reckoning:**

[image]

Which one am I supposed to believe?

Comment: @laaposto: my answer here contains the actual rules; Chris's answer there is lacking that detail, and is actually wrong (the count difference is purely down to tag edits, which Chris doesn't mention). We should probably close *in the other direction* here.

Comment: I forgot about tag only edits not counting, so this should be the master question and answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For the badge, you can believe the counter in the review queue. The badge has *specific constraints* as to what edits count and the counter in the review queue takes those constraints into account.

The revisions list in your review includes edits on your own posts, multiple edits on posts, and tag-only edits, so that count is higher.

The full list of exceptions for edits which therefore do not count towards the badge is:

- Edits on deleted posts do not count
- Edits to your own posts do not count
- Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
- Each edited post counts only once, regardless of how many additional edits you may submit

(sourced from the [central badges FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/140890)).

The editors tab adds all tag-only edits; so you made 429 - 337 = 92 tag-only edits on posts that are not your own. See [What kind of edits are counted in /users?tab=editors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81655/what-kind-of-edits-are-counted-in-userstab-editors)

And the 520 count in your profile then adds edits on your own posts as well as count multiple revisions on the same post separately.

Comment: This information should be available as a description or a tooltip for the badges on the Badge page, rather than buried somewhere in MSE.

Answer (score 20):

I agree with TylerH's comments re: making the badge description clearer, and as a result have changed the description of the **Copy Editor** badge from:

> Edited 500 posts

To:

> Edited 500 posts (excluding own or deleted posts and tag edits)

Which I feel is more descriptive and useful in determining the requirements of the badge. This will be live in the next production build (meta: > `rev 2014.10.16.2667`, q&a: > `rev 2014.10.16.1945`).