# Why do the suggested edit counts in my profile differ from those on the review page?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

When I go to my profile and check "suggestions" under "activity", it shows 118 suggestions (including both approved and rejected edits):

[image: 118 Suggestions]

However, when I click on "more" in the suggested edits review page, I see 136 suggestions (117 approved + 19 rejected):

[image: Editor Stats: Srikanth had 117 edit suggestions approved, and 19 edit suggestions rejected]

Why is there a difference between these two numbers?

Comment: Thanks. I checked it out its about the progress for badges where certain edits are not counted but why would there be a difference in this case?

Comment: Read Martijn's answer on that question- He describes how the numbers are picked up for each stat pretty well. Looking again, it does seem to be missing editor stats.

Comment: Taking a guess on it, it might be the edit conflicts. Perhaps they don't appear on the suggested page on your profile. But of course, I don't know for sure.

Comment: Yes that question is about badge progress, revisions and editors under users. This question is about suggestions and editor stats

Comment: I see edit conflicts also in the suggestions tab so it might not be the case.

Comment: **Possible duplicate of:** [Why are there three different numbers for the amount of revisions I've made? And which one is real?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274478/why-are-there-three-different-numbers-for-the-amount-of-revisions-ive-made-and)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Please check the edit history of the question to see the differences between the questions

Comment: I did see the edit history, an invalid edit and an invalid edit summary that is more of a conversation. I posted my possible duplicate comment here for future readers, because I feel it's a valid use of comments. Please flag for removal if you find it inappropiate.

Comment: I thought you flagged it as a duplicate and this was the automatic comment which came with it and I saw a down vote as well. when this question was marked as a duplicate and in its description it said mention how my question was different and hence I made the edit to explain the differences.

Comment: I reviewed your question [in the review queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/1894). Voting is disabled in queues and making assumptions about who downvoted your post is not productive. My name appears is the edit history - "Closed by....". I didn't flag, I didn't downvote, I only reviewed and left a comment. Good luck.

Comment: Please to clarify I said  "I saw a down vote as well" I didn't say that I saw your down vote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suggestions section of your profile doesn't show suggested edits on posts that are now deleted.  The count of total suggested edits when viewing a suggested edit includes edits to deleted posts.

Comment: Oh got it thanks for the info. My suggested edits reputation will then be based on the approved suggestions in the suggestions section right?

Comment: @Srikanth Correct.