# How I find number of post I edited so far?

Tags: support

Is there a way to view number of post I have edited so far. I didn't see any link to view it.

Comment: I think you're looking for this list: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4035943/anjibman?tab=activity&sort=revisions

Comment: If you are thinking of progress towards the badge, that list does not give you the count. Excluded from the badge are edits on your own posts and, I think, someone will chip in, tag-only or title-only edits. Throw edits on deleted posts into the mix, and I've never been able to keep track of what is what, and despite doing quite a lot of editing, I have no clue how many the system counts, and where, for any given analysis of edits I've performed. On your profile, as all your edits go for review until you have 2000 rep, look at suggestions for edits which are not on your own posts.

Comment: I don't understand why someone will downvote this question. There must be good explanation for that.

Comment: Probably because you didn't look very hard.

Comment: @Jongware - Yes I didn't look very hard ... wait ... in "revision" or "suggestion" ... lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your profile page, there is an "all actions" tab, which you can constrain to revisions only. Those are your edits.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4035943/anjibman?tab=activity&sort=revisions

Comment: Ahh... it called revised not edited. Confusing with badge description!!

Comment: Wouldn't "Suggestions" be more useful? It lists the same as the revisions but also rejected edits as well.

Comment: @Jongware it is a different thing. Edits and suggested edits are related, but not the same. The former can't be "rejected".

Comment: I mentioned it because it lists the edits *made by the user*. Whether these edits were then accepted or not is another concern.

Comment: @Jongware: If you take the suggestions page, you get all suggestions. But you don't suggest when you can edit directly, like always on your own posts, with 2K on everything but tag-wikis, with 20K everywhere. Also, only some suggestions get upgraded to edits, as Oded says.

Comment: @αƞjiβ Note that the number that Oded links to here is **not** the number used to award badges like Copy Editor. See this question and the accepted answer to understand how to get all the different numbers, and what exactly they mean: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274478/why-are-there-three-different-numbers-for-the-amount-of-revisions-ive-made-and.