# Not Getting Reputation From Edits

Tags: support, edits, reputation

I have read the [How Does Reputation Work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) post and saw that you will not get reputation from edits past 2K reputation and that you are also limited to 1,000 reputation points from edits.

My situation does not fit either of these conditions and I am not getting reputation for my edits.

You can see that I have only 1,489 reputation and that I have 347 edits approved.

I have searched the site looking at similar topics, but have found no answer.

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: Go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation and scroll to the bottom. It'll tell you if you've reached it or not. https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23358825 also says you have over 600 approved. There's a meta post on the difference between edits and revisions somewhere, but I can't find it. It explains the number you thought you had.

Comment: @Zoe, thanks for clearing that up. I went to the first link and saw that it says I reached the cap.

Comment: @zoe *There's a meta post on the difference between edits and revisions somewhere* [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298666/posts-edited-on-my-profile-is-not-the-same-as-edits-in-users-list/298672#298672) but it doesn't cover revisions?

Comment: @rene That one is actually better. Thought about [this number](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10632369/tomerpacific?tab=activity&sort=revisions) though.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274478/why-are-there-three-different-numbers-for-the-amount-of-revisions-ive-made-and cc @rene

Comment: With more than 2,000 reputation points, you get reputation points for tag wiki edits (until you reach 5,000 reputation points).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see all your approved suggested edits here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10632369/tomerpacific?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Once you've had 500 approved edit suggestions (aka 1k rep gain), you won't earn any more reputation. As [Zoe's link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23358825) shows, you've made over 500 approved suggested edits so far, so the only way for you to get rep now is by receiving upvotes or bounties on your questions and/or answers.

Comment: The cap for suggested edits is 1000 rep which could be 500 approved edits if you get the rep gain for each of them. The link you showed also shows rejected edits as well as approved so it showing 500+ suggested edits does not mean 500+ have been approved. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work

Comment: @JoeW Zoe's link that Tyler included shows the full summary "tomerpacific had 635 edit suggestions approved, and 100 edit suggestions rejected"

Comment: @DavyM When I click on the link in the answer it shows 594 suggested edits and not how many are approved. The other link just goes to a single suggested edit

Comment: @JoeW Yup, and that [single suggested edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxMOS.png) displays, just like all suggested edits do, the editor's stats. If the editor has 594 undeleted suggested edits, and they've had more than 600 approved in total, it's wholly reasonable that their total number of undeleted accepted edits is above 500.

Comment: @JoeW There are over 500 approved edits *in addition to a number of rejected edits* on the link I posted. It was implied in my answer that OP would do a little legwork to check for themselves how many were approved.